# android sqlight invoked from class

Tags: java, sql, android, android-widget

I am using Gamelogic class which implements no one (just object to be honest )

I want from him to set a database where the game screen ask the logic questions and the last ask the sql question without all the Context usage , just to keep it simple .

is it possible ? if not what is the alternative?

Can someone show me little example?  I am lost and the notepad example does not help

thanks, yoav.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You HAVE to use a `Context` in that case. But you are lucky, all activities are `Context`s so what you have to do is passing a reference of your activity to the `Gamelogic` class. For instance, you can pass it as an argument to its constructor:

```
public class Gamelogic{
    private Context context;
    public Gamelogic(Context context){
        this.context = context;
        // do what ever you want with the context object
    }
    // more complex logic here
}
```

On your activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity{

    // foo bar baz blablablabla

    public void someWhereOnYourActitity(){
        new Gamelogic(YourActivity.this);
    }
}
```

Comment: does it makes a difference if i send 

1.this.getApplicationContext()

OR

2.YourActivity.this

?

Comment: Actually no... they reference the same context.